# Split Varchar max field into multiple columns based on a Semicolon

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am writing up a report where I have a varchar(max) column that has data in it separated by a ";" semicolon. The end users are asking for the report to break apart this one column and return it as a series of columns.

I am not sure how to do this.

The data has variable lengths based on the status of the customer. Some of the columns only have 60 characters in it, some have 400+ characters.

The data looks somewhat like this:

```
Result 1 = aaaaaaaa; bbbbbbbbbbbb; ccccccccccccccccccccccccc; ddddddddddddd;
Result 2 = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa; bbbbbbbbb;
Result 3 = aaaaaaaaaaaaaa; bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb; ccccccccccccccccccccccccc;
```

The flip side of this is that if I were to break each semicolon section out, I could end up with 40 - 50 columns worth of data, while others might end up being just 3. (if that makes sense)

Everything else in the report is a piece of cake, it is just the splitting of this one column that has me questioning the whole endeavor.

I guess my question here is:
How would I break apart this one column into multiple based off the Semicolon delimiter?

Comment: Tough luck... Storing data like that causes a lot of trouble.

Comment: Yea it does. This isn't the first time this particular setup has bit me in the butt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the helps of a CROSS APPLY and an little XML.  As you can see, the XML portion is easy to expand or contract as necessary.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'aaaaaaaa; bbbbbbbbbbbb; ccccccccccccccccccccccccc; ddddddddddddd;'),
(2,'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa; bbbbbbbbb;'),
(3,'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa; bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb; ccccccccccccccccccccccccc;')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.SomeCol,';','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Trying this now! Thank you for the response

Comment: @user1949329 I have inherited ugly structures as well.

Comment: @user1949329 FYI, the code within the CROSS APPLY make a good TVF where you pass the String and the Delimiter as a parameter.  So replace(A.SomeCol,';'   becomes replace(@String,@Delimiter